# HTML form data pass to AWS lambda API endpoint issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a basic html form which contains contact information fields. Like this,

```html
<form method="post" action="https://MYAPIPATHISHERE.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/contact">
    <input name="website" placeholder="Website URL" type="text">

    <input name="name" class="email input-standard-grey" placeholder="Your Name" type="text">
    
 <input name="email" placeholder="Email Address" type="email">

    <input name="phone" class="email input-standard-grey" placeholder="Phone" type="text">
  
    <textarea name="message" class="email input-standard-grey" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

  
    <button>Submit Now</button>
                    
</form>
```

I have a working AWS Lambda API endpoint like this

https://MYAPIPATHISHERE.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/contact

I tried to submit the form. But it's not working. Sometimes showing an Internal server error as the response and sometimes Cross Origin error. My site is hosted in Github pages. This API endpoint works well in Postman and Curl. Lambda function is coded in NodeJS.

Comment: Are you using mapping templates on your response? Or, are you using Lambda Proxy integration? It would be helpful if in your question you include your `serverless.yml` and a snippet showing how you call `callback` in your handler.

Comment: HTML post submits are cross origin so the error doesn't have anything to do with CORS headers.  Is your API gateway configured to handle application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type?

Comment: How to configure this?

Comment: I'm using serverless framework.

Comment: I'm passing headers like this.

headers: { 
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", 
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
      },

Comment: Now some far issue fixed. There was an issue with JSON.parse(). So i get directly event data without parsing. So now it works without an issue in postman urlencode data. But timestamp values adding and field data not passing. So dynamo db record adding with empty data for those field values. Can anyone help me to proceed from here?

Comment: I checked this issue more using serverless local development environment with local dynamodb. I noticed that form data not getting properly and shows values as 'undefined'. Hardcoded values are saving to the database without an issue.